# coffeescript vs typescript vs JSX vs dart vs fantom

Tags: coffeescript, dart, typescript, jsx, fantom

TypeScript website offer the following D3 example is there any comparison of the same D3  codes for the following languages available:

- CoffeeScript
- TypeScript
- JSX
- Dart
- Fantom

It would be interested to see which one is really easier to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a great question for programmers.stackexchange.com. This question is likely to be closed and voted down, because there is no right answer, and thus is a poor fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: thank you I posted it there and voted to delete the current post here.

Comment: Can you post a link to that post?  I did an internet search and this page came up.